# Printing odd no.s from 1 to 100 in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Language: Intel assembly
Targetted processor: 8086

I want to accomplish the subject and using the following code to achieve that:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000H
.CODE
MAIN PROC
MOV DX, 0002H
MOV CX, 0064H
BODY:
MOV DX, 0002H
MOV BX, 0064H
SUB BX, CX
MOV AX, BX
DIV DL
CMP AH, 1H
JNE GO
PRINT:
MOV AX, BX
ADD AX, 0H
AAA
OR AX, 3030H
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
ROL AX, 1
MOV DL, AL
MOV AH, 2H
INT 21H
MOV AX, BX
ADD AX, 0H
AAA
OR AX, 3030H
MOV DL, AL
MOV AH, 2H
INT 21H
GO: LOOP BODY
MAIN ENDP 
END
```

But when I run the code it, it goes normal for 1,3,5....15 then it starts again from 1...It never prints 17 or higher digits. Any help? I'm attaching the output as well to visualize what I'm getting.

[image]

---

**Working version**

Because of wrong logic and implementation I was not getting the desired output... Now I got the clue from the accepted answer and now I have the fully working code.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
LF EQU '0DH'
.CODE
MAIN PROC
MOV CX,0001H
MOV DX,0
BACK: MOV DL, CH
OR DL, 30H
MOV AH, 2
INT 21H
MOV DL, CL
OR DL, 30H
MOV AH, 2
INT 21H
CMP CL, 9
MOV DL, 20H
MOV AH, 2
INT 21H
JGE UNITSREACHED
ADD CL, 2
JMP UNITSUNREACHED
UNITSREACHED:
ADD CH, 1
MOV CL, 1
CMP CH , 9
JG EXIT
UNITSUNREACHED: JMP BACK
EXIT:
END MAIN 
MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: 1. Assembler code is not HTML. 2. "*Enter image description here*" means you should enter a textual description of the image you're posting.

Comment: Thanks for Your advice... I'll take care of these things from now on...

Comment: If you can't use `rol ax,8` (e.g. because you're restricted to only 8086, not 286 or whatever), then use `xchg al,ah` like a normal person, not `rol ax,1` 8 times.  `rol ax,8` is faster on modern CPUs, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    MOV AX, BX
    ADD AX, 0H
    AAA
```

here `bx` is 0..99 value, then zero is added to it and the `AAA` will keep values 0..9 intact, and for values 10..99 it will set `ah` to `1` and `al` to 0..15.

And it makes no sense (values 0..99 are not "BCD unpacked" type of values), nor I can figure out from the comments, what algorithm you were trying to implement. Nor is your code in any way efficient.

Why don't you start with string `"01"` and print it 50 times, each time adding `2` to the second letter, and when it is over `'9'`, then adjusting it by `-10` and adding `+1` to the first letter.

Unless you want to practice arithmetic, then just two things:

1) to test if value is odd, use `test some_register,1` bit test, every odd integer value must have least significant bit set, because that's how you get 2<sup>0</sup> value added to the integer.

2) convert multidigit value to string by some different algorithm, not sure where you did pick up `AAA`, that's very unusual to see in beginners code (or any other BCD related instruction, although the `AAM` and `AAD` can be sometimes tricked into interesting effects, when coding for size, but that's not something a beginner should be worried about, user rather `div by 10` logical straightforward code).

---

edit: and as always, if you don't understand why your code does anything, use debugger to see yourself, what is happening (+ cross-check with instruction reference guide). Actually use it even if you think the code is doing the correct thing, because the likelihood of having there something you don't really want is still huge, without debugging your assembly code you can hardly tell if it is even remotely correct (just running it and receiving correct output does not count, that's not even worth the time of the run).